# How to display images on swagger UI?

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui

I'm testing the API and must obtain files (jpg and png). Why can't correctly display the API result image on Swagger to see if it's working properly?
[image: Swagger UI]

My code

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Obter arquivos de permalink", response = FileSystemResource.class, produces = "image/png")
    @RequestMapping(value = "{validacaoId}/{permalinkId}/permalink/{pecaFile}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable("validacaoId") String validacaoId,
                                      @PathVariable("permalinkId") String permalinkId,
                                      @PathVariable("pecaFile") String pecaFile) {
        return new FileSystemResource(permalinkService.getFile(validacaoId, permalinkId, pecaFile));
    }
```